# How to turn assertions off when using a Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, terminal, assertions

I'm using a makefile in Xcode to compile my C programs, but I don't know how I would go about disabling assertions when using the makefile to compile my code.

Previously I've been using `-DNDEBUG` to toggle assertions in the terminal.

Comment: You still use `-DNDEBUG` to turn them off (though are you sure you want to do that?).  The question is: how is the C compiler command line formed and where do you get to insert your own flags? For my own work, I build `CFLAGS` from a number of pieces, and I reserve UFLAGS (user flags) for setting on the `make` command line to set extra flags into the command line.  That is not a general solution, though.  In extremis, you can use `make CC='clang -DNDEBUG'` to replace the normal C compiler (`clang`) with `clang -DNDEBUG`.  However, that's unlikely to be the best, or even only, way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the `-DNDEBUG` flag as part of your Makefile. If you want to keep it organized, set up a variable called `CFLAGS`. For example:

```
CC=clang
CFLAGS=-DNDEBUG
DEPS = stackover.h

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: Then would I have to add something else when I run the program.  Previously I was using:

    "make"
then

    "./my_program"
to run my program from terminal.