# Do assertions in C code make it to Swift-iOS production apps?

Tags: ios, c, swift

I have C-language files in my Swift-iOS project and there are assertions throughout, such as the following:

```
LinkedGeoLoop *addNewLinkedLoop(LinkedGeoPolygon *polygon) {
    LinkedGeoLoop *loop = H3_MEMORY(calloc)(1, sizeof(*loop));
    assert(loop != NULL);
    return addLinkedLoop(polygon, loop);
}
```

I thought I remember reading that assertions are ignored in production environments, or something like that? If I ship this project to the App Store with these C assertions in the the project's files, are they honored or ignored in the production environment?

Comment: No code that you require to be executed should ever be placed in an assertion.  That includes especially testing for function failures, such as your example appears to be doing.  This is because depending on how the code is compiled, the asserted expression might not be evaluated at all.  That's controlled by whether the `NDEBUG` macro is defined at compilation time.  I don't know how that factors into your particular context, but any way around, code such as you show is semantically flawed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that's very interesting, thank you for that. The C files are actually from Uber's H3, a geospatial-indexing library. H3 is what Uber itself uses for geoquerying, and also what I use, and so my natural inclination was not to tinker with the code. Here is their assertion file in case you were curious (https://github.com/uber/h3/blob/master/src/h3lib/include/h3Assert.h). They're very good at commenting and explaining their thought processes.

Comment: Uber seems to take appropriate care, but they have to go out of their way to use `assert()`.  Note in particular that they say of expressions used as arguments to their `ALWAYS()` and `NEVER()` macros that "Such expressions could be omitted from the code completely."  That's best taken as a requirement on how these macros are to be used, not as a claim about compilers.  Note, however, that the condition for the argument expressions of those macros to be evaluated is different from the condition for expressions that are (only) `assert()`ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether C assertions are enabled is [controlled by the preprocessor macro `NDEBUG`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19738210/5133585). It has nothing to do with the Swift, which has its own [`assert`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/assert(_:_:file:line:)).

Check the preprocessor macros for Apple Clang in the build settings in Xcode. If you don't want `assert`s in release mode, add it in.

[image]

Also note that there is also an option for "Foundation Assertions", which is yet another different thing. That is Foundation's [`NSAssert`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsassert?language=objc).

Comment: So, to be clear, adding `NDEBUG` here (as in your screenshot) will specifically disable C assertions in release mode? A quick aside: how does the preprocessor determine if the environment is release or debug? For example, when I install an app onto a physical device through Xcode, is it treated as debug if I launch the app through Xcode and release if I launch it from the device?

Comment: That all makes perfect sense, thank you for the clear explanation. I've added `NDEBUG` but this Clang preprocessor field is confusing. I see `$(inherited)` multiple times (I'll have to research that). And when I expand the field by double clicking it, it says very different things then when it wasn't expanded. I wish it were just a text file I could edit in code. I hate interfacing with a GUI in programming.

Comment: I thought these were Clang macros not GCC?

Comment: Omgosh you're so smart. One last question, what is the difference between adding `NDEBUG` under release in the project's build settings versus the target's build settings? I understand the project is the project and the target (of which there can be multiple) is the finished product, but what on earth is the project's release mode?

Comment: @lurningtookoad I think that's where `$(inherited)` comes in :) The project's build setting is inherited by the target, if you say `$(inherited)` for that setting.

Comment: And to be certain, for my use case, I should add it in the target's build settings, correct?

Comment: @lurningtookoad (The comments are kind getting out of control so I deleted some of mine) If your app has multiple targets, and you want this to apply to all of them, then I would put it in the project settings and use `$(inherited)` for each of the targets. Otherwise, I'd just put it in the target's build settings.